# Formating variable within a string interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I have a string interpolation that looks like this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
            <% @top_ten_cashflows.each do |transaction|%>
            <li class="list-group-item"> <%=" #{ transaction.date.format('%b') } - #{transaction.category.name} - #{transaction.amount}"%></li>
            <%end%>
        </ul>
```

Rails brings up the following error when i try to format the date:

```
NoMethodError at /Dashboard
private method `format' called for Wed, 20 Jul 2016:Date
```

The controller looks as follows:

```
    def dashboard
    #@cashflows = current_user.cashflows
   # cashflows_sums =@cashflows.inject do |sum,element| 
     @cashflows = Cashflow.where(user_id: current_user.id).joins(:category)
    @top_ten_cashflows = @cashflows.order(:date).limit(10)

end
```

How do i get the date to be formatted within the string interpolation with the day and short month.

Comment: Use strftime method to format date

Comment: Or much better, use I18n localization, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
transaction.date.strftime('%b')
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strftime

Comment: O i didn't know strtftime that was an actual function. thought its a variable. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, use [I18n localization Date/Time formats](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats), it is easy, flexible and adds an extra level of customization per locale.

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<p><%= l Time.now, format: :short %></p>
```

You can use the [default Rails Date/Tme formats](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml) or add your custom  formats.